# Xamarin.Android layout issue

Tags: android, xamarin, layout, xamarin.android

I'm doing a tutorial which involves placing 3 objects on the screen. The tutorial says 'Drag a Plain Text widget from the Toolbox to the design surface and place it underneath the Text (Large) widget. Placement of the widget will not occur until you move the mouse pointer to a place in the layout that can accept the widget.'

I do this but all three objects end up on top of each other.[3 objects on top of each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1piL.png). I've looked at Layout properties but nothing seems to work.

How do I separate them so they are in a column? Thank you.

Comment: Is it a `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: Try do it by hand on the axml editor, don't use the layout editor

Comment: Post your xaml code.

Comment: The Xamarin layout editor is not always great with regards to rendering and the resulting layout may need adjustment in many cases. If you could add the source we could point out what the issue is.